# klarna merchant_checkbox_text is disable

Tags: magento2, configuration, payment-methods, third-party-module, klarna

I am using klarna m2 module in klarna checkout I want to unable merchant checkbox under 
**sales->checkout->klarna** 
checkout option.

I am able to make it active but when I tried to change its text this merchant_checkbox_text is disable.

I checked in code visibility is depend on **merchant_checkbox** and I make it active but still its inactive

[image]

Comment: you need to setup and API from Klarana

Comment: Your merchant ID for API interaction. (Provided to you by Klarna)

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in klarna module. They have paramently off the merchant_checkbox_textbox by putting value 1. need to add patch to resolve this issue